# ORA-01017 when connecting through jdbc thin driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, oracle11g

Using

- the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4) JDBC Driver "ojdbc6.jar" (from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)),
- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production (verified by doing "select * from v$version")

I'm trying to connect to the database from a Java application using the JDBC Driver. This fails with a "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" message.

- I'm 100% certain that the username and password I'm inputting in my code is correct. I have verified this by going as far as copy-pasting the values from my code in the connection manager of SQLDeveloper, where connecting works fine.
- The ojdbc6.jar-file is imported in my Eclipse project (as a library).
- The TNS string is copied from a tnsping to the TNS name which works in SQLDeveloper.
- I've additionally verified that the username / password for the server I'm using are not case sensitive (by connecting in SQL developer using an uppercased version of my username and password, and trying the same with a lowercased version), as there was some issue with that on earlier JDBC drivers.

Things installed on my computer (over which I have no power):

- Oracle Client 11.2.0
- SQLDeveloper Version 4.0.1.14

I don't think these are interfering, as removing the ojdbc6.jar from the libraries the Eclipse project uses gives rise to no output (no errors, also no output from the select-clause), so I'm fairly sure the thin driver is in fact being used.

I've created a small test application to demonstrate the problem:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class OracleTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=13301)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=something)))";

        String username = "myUser";
        String password = "myPass";

        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database,username,password);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select 'hello' from dual");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("output: " + rs.getString(0));
            }
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Done!
```

Comment: That error is about as straight-forward as you get with Oracle.  What happens when you log in with the same URL or same connect string through SQL Developer or sqlplus?

Comment: Are you sure that that it has tob ADDRESS_LIST=.. in the database connection String? I thought it is just ADDRESS=..

Comment: Have you tried anoother conenction pattern like jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE

Comment: @wrschneider99: from SQL developer, I get a "Status : Success" when using the copy-pasted Connect Identifier (connection type TNS).

Comment: @RenéWinkler: I have now tried with the alternative connection pattern you suggested - I get the same error.

Comment: @RenéWinkler: I've tried with just the ADDRESS instead of first the ADDRESS_LIST and then the ADDRESS. Still same issue.

Comment: Try using two slashes after the @

Comment: Does your password contain any special characters? Oracle is too dumb to lie most of the time.

Comment: @RenéWinkler:I did. Didn't work. Please note I used the exact connect identifier in SQLDeveloper (copy paste) and it worked, so I really doubt this is where the issue is.

Comment: @mmmmmpie: no, it doesn't. The password works in other tools BTW.

Comment: Try omitting the Class.forName... line. What java version do you use?

Comment: @RenéWinkler: tried it, no difference. I'm using jre7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friendly DB admin came to the rescue, and found that this is actually an Oracle bug:

```
Problem Description:
--------------------
When trying to connect by using the JDBC THIN 11g driver to a database 11g 
using Enterprise User Security (EUS) connections throw invalid username/

When usign the JDBC OCI driver the connection can be made.
```

And now - hold on to your hats:

```
Available Workarounds:
----------------------
Use OCI.
```

Note that I used 11.2.0.4, while the bug says

```
Tested Versions:
----------------
JDBC THIN Driver 11.1.0.6.0 and 11.1.0.7.0
```

So apparently it's been around for a while. I'm not sure I get this - why are they bringing out new versions of this driver if it fails on connecting you to the database properly? Seems this would be the first issue everybody runs into when using the thin driver?

But then, our local DB admin hero dug this up:

```
Set the property oracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 for the JDBC connection by passing the option oracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 on the command line.  

For example:
java -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 <Java Class>

There is no loss of security when following this workaround.
```

In Eclipse, I've added this line to the VM arguments (Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM arguments -> add -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3) and, lo and behold, I can finally get into the database.

Comment: Can you please give some more details? I need to implement this solution badly. What do you mean by "=o3 <Java Class>" ? Should i specify my class name after o3?

Comment: @ShreyasSG: when you start your java program, you're calling java on the command line somewhere. Usually like: "java myClassName". 

Now do the same but write "java -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 myClassName"

Comment: @JayVeelnCorp I modified the connection string. I used /sName instead of :sID. This solved my problem. Also, I read somewhere on Oracle site that there is some bug in JDBC. Thanks for your reply though! :)

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem using Tibco Jasper Studio 6.5 with ojdbc8, I tried setting  -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 in Jaspersoft Studio.ini file, but... it din't fix the issue. Could I be making a mistake in setting Jasper Studio for this option? Also, the issue depends on the DB server setup, doesn't it? A different DB doesn't show this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

EUS (Entreprise Users) are supported in the JDBC-thin driver starting in 11.2.0.3 but did you verify that indeed the user "myUser" is defined as an EUS in the database? EUS users are defined in a central directory (OID for example) and are not normal user you create in the database by doing "create user".

One additional note: SQLDeveloper uses the JDBC thin driver. So if you can connect with SQLDeveloper then you should also be able to connect from your standalone JDBC program. Just make sure SQLDeveloper uses the same jdbc jar as the one you're using. If you want to check the version of the JDBC driver that you're using just do "java -jar ojdbc7.jar" which will print the version.

Comment: I could indeed connect with the same user using SQLDeveloper. In the SQLDeveloper installation directory, I can only find ojdbc6.jar (in jdbc/lib), which returns "Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Mon_Aug_29_23:34:29_PDT_2011".

Answer (score 0):

Similar exception can occur if username and password is specified (even empty values) in oracle thin **wallet** connection configurations. Below configurations would work.

```
    System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", [wallet location]);
    System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", [Tns location]);

    "url" =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@tns_alias"
    "driver_class" =  "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
```