# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-connection, aix

I'm getting the follwing exception while trying to connect to a database:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:675)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:258)
        at com.alting.db.ManagerDB.getConnection(ManagerDB.java:57)
        at com.alting.db.ManagerDB.openConnection(ManagerDB.java:75)
        at com.alting.med.EventGenerator.exportData(EventGenerator.java:220)
        at com.alting.med.Main.main(Main.java:252)
```

here the method used to get the connection:

```
private Connection getConnection(String url, String driverClass, String user, String password) throws ManagerDBException 
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driverClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ManagerDBException(e.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
      this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      throw new ManagerDBException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return this.connection;
}
```

But even when the params (url, password..) are hardcoded, I still get the exception.

Could you tell me how to fix this problem ?
thanks

Comment: How do you call getConnection?

Comment: could you provide the harcoded password and or user? Is it an empty password? if so an empty `String` is equal to `null` for oracle.

Comment: none of the params is empty

Comment: I will suggest to add a null check to your code before setting password and please paste the complete stack trace of exception. How are you running this code, is it via a IDE? Do you have multiple versions of this file ? Is it possible that its being picked from some other place?

Comment: I update my post with the stacktrace.
the program is started on server with a shell script and there is only one version of the file.

Comment: I has had error-messages like this; the reason was a bit strange: the Java JRE wasn't properly installed (via installp) only the files of /usr/java* were copied. Somehow this mattered. Proper install of JRE fixed the problem.

Comment: Or maybe it was a minor version-difference? Now I think this error message means _something is not okay, go find out_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears the problem is linked to the "-Djava.endorsed.dirs" parameter from the java startup command line.

By removing this one, everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

This post solved my problem

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

[ORA-01017 when connecting through jdbc thin driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945312/ora-01017-when-connecting-through-jdbc-thin-driver)

Added `-Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3` parameter to the java startup line.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing same issue... What do you mean by adding that parameter to the java startup line? I am getting ` -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3: command not found`. I am pretty new.. can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an empty string password Oracle JDBC will consider that equivalent to **NULL**.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when using JDK6 and it went away when switching to JDK8 (use the latest version of JDK8).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, (where all the jars, including ojdbc8 is in the folder ./libs), I change from

```
java -Djava.ext.dir=libs/ MainClass
```

to

```
java -cp "./libs/*" MainClass
```

Then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem with spring boot app when externalized all the jars. The java.ext.dirs doesn't work with oracle driver 19.x, throws "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied".
The application worked fine with fat-jar.

I was able to resolve the issue with "export CLASSPATH".