# Unable to connect to Oracle XE via JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This is my Java Code: The error says the password is null but clearly it is not. Any help is appreciated...

```
public class OracleConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1";
        String user = "constantin";
        String password = "tiger";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database.");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menagerie");

            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the database.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the error ...

Could not connect to the database.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:702)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:603)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:598)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1710)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:819)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:1041)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:443)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:462)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTHWithO5Logon(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1375)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1322)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.authenticateWithPassword(T4CConnection.java:1500)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.authenticateUserForLogon(T4CConnection.java:1443)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:812)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1101)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:104)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at ca.menagerie.core.main.OracleConnect.main(OracleConnect.java:12)
```

I am using the following driver ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar
Oracle XE 21c

This is how I initialized everything:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jun 14 02:10:21 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: / as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> select name from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDB$SEED
XEPDB1

SQL> connect sys/kryptonite@localhost:1521/XEPDB1 as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> create user constantin identified by tiger default tablespace users quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to constantin;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect constantin/tiger@localhost:1521/XEPDB1;

Connected.

SQL> create table menagerie(id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into menagerie values (1234);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from menagerie;
        ID
----------
      1234
SQL>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609280/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01005-null-password-given-logon-denied)

Comment: //JDBC and database properties.
 private static final String DB_DRIVER = 
             "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 private static final String DB_URL = 
          "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
 use url without forward slahs and try

Comment: none of these worked

Comment: how much more minimal can i be?  the code is exactly as i gave it to you

Comment: Ill ty using a different oracle jdbc driver later today ....  ive never had such a pain connecting to oracle before

Comment: i did state that already:      I am using the following driver ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar Oracle XE 21c ....   like i said, ill try a different driver later, thanks

Comment: Sorry - I missed that - my apologies. That is almost certainly the problem, in that case. My other comments are probably not relevant - I will delete them. Using `ojdbc11` should work for you.

Comment: No luck, i even uninstalled it to 18C using oracle 8 driver ... same type of errors

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@localhost:1521:xe works for me, but agree, oracle driver is a joke

Answer (score 1):

*String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1"* is wrong.

Try removing // from the url.