# AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3

Tags: sql, oracle

I just had an issue connecting to databases in my SQL Developer with the error

> 'unsupported verifier type'

I did some research on Google since our DBA team could not assist with this error. The suggestion based on my search was to add the line

```
 AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3
```

to the sqldeveloper.conf file.
Can somebody explain the importance of adding this line? What exactly does this line do?

Thank you.

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945312/ora-01017-when-connecting-through-jdbc-thin-driver - you shouldn't be seeing that in newer versions of SQLDev, and you can also use a THICK connection apparently

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. On a high level, can you please explain the difference between thin and thick database drivers?

Comment: I will try :) THIN is a PURE JDBC connection. THICK says, do this connection over SQL*NET - using an Oracle Client. When doing this, you are getting as close as possible to how SQL*Plus would run/negotiate a connection with the database. I talk about this a bit, here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/01/password-resets-no-longer-require-a-thick-connection-oracle-client-in-sql-developer/

Comment: our latest offerings of SQLDev use Java 1.8 an 12cR2 JDBC drivers - i would expect this bug to be 'fixed' in those environments, say SQL Developer version 17.4

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Oracle side where certain applications especially running on WebSphere 7 with JDK 1.6 and ojdbc6.jar are not able to login to the Database. This is because of an Oracle driver “issue” when dealing with external 3rd party JCE libraries such as BouncyCastle.

Ref: https://vinaynotes.wordpress.com/tag/thinlogoncapability/

StackOverFlow Ref: [ORA-01017 when connecting through jdbc thin driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945312/ora-01017-when-connecting-through-jdbc-thin-driver)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So by adding the line 'AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3', what are we doing?

Comment: Only a person who was included in the development team of JDK 1.6 can know the issue and how this line solves it. He wouldn't tell us, kinda sure.. @DChoi

Comment: Haha, I see. I guess they don't want to share their "secret recipe". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We found this parameter setting was necessary when authenticating to accounts that were using LDAP/Active Directory authentication ... IE enterprise user accounts (EUS) oracle accounts.   Without this setting attempted logons received invalid id/password errors.